# Jquery Multi Step Double Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wizard

Guys. I'm a newbie Frontend Dev.

I have a problem when using Jquery Multi Step.

I have to double click the submit button to proceed to the next Step.

Can anyone please help me to make it only One Click?

Thanks for Help.

```
if (stepIndex === 0 || stepIndex === 1 || stepIndex === 2 || stepIndex === 2) {
  step1($step, $pag);
} else {
  step3($step, $pag);
}
```

Here's [The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asktouche/jvho9dmf)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer would be to replace `$('.button.not-finished').click(function(){})` with the following:

```
$('.button.not-finished').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('finished');
   var $btn = $(this),
      $step = $btn.parents('.modal-body'),
      stepIndex = $step.index(),
      $pag = $('span').eq(stepIndex);

    if (stepIndex === 0 || stepIndex === 1 || stepIndex === 2 || stepIndex === 2) {
      step1($step, $pag);
    } else {
      step3($step, $pag);
    }

});
```

stepanim() is pointless now, and you may remove it unless it's used elsewhere.

**UPDATE 1:** I noticed that you said you're new to this somewhat, so I'll give a bit of clarification, and hopefully you'll be able to solve this yourself next time. The first thing to note is that somewhere, code is getting triggered to do the stuff that you are wanting. We'll name that code *toBeMoved*, just for it to be easier to explain. The only problem is that it is happening at the wrong time (wrong place in the code). So find the code that triggers when you want, or create it yourself. Here, `$('.button.not-finished').click(function(){})` does exist, and that is what gets triggered when the button is clicked. Then take *toBeMoved*, and put it inside of the onclick function. The last step is to remove anything that is now irrelevant.